# The requested resource was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

this is my controller :

```
 $leagues =DB::table('leagues')
         ->select('leagues.id', 'leagues.name', 'leagues.ar_name', 'leagues.short_name', 'leagues.logo', 'countries.name as country')
         ->leftJoin('countries', 'leagues.country_id', '=', 'countries.country_id')
         ->orderBy('leagues.id')
         ->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.league.league',compact('leagues'));
```

this is my route :

```
Route::get('/leagues', [LeagueController::class, 'index'])->name('leagues.index');
```

but i get this error :
[image]

Comment: i did this but still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you have a folder with same name in `public` directory.

Answer (score 0):

you may have folder named leagues in your public folder, so i suggest you to change the route url

Comment: ok you suggest to rename the folder

Comment: Wouldn't it be found then?

Comment: in that case the error would be different (view .... not found.)

Comment: i'm not suggesting to rename the folder, i'm suggesting to rename the url in route, as long as you call the route by name it'll be okay, and it have nothing to do with 'view not found', because view is in resource folder